# Regex don't capture the group after matching properly

Tags: c#, regex

I have two separate strings:

```
1. "@colorVariableOne: @color_white;"
2. "@colorVariableTwo: #008000;"
```

I am using the following regex pattern to test if the string match:

```
string colorVariablePattern = @"(@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+): (#[0-9a-fA-F]{3,})|.*(@color_[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+).*;";
```

The pattern matches both of the strings successfully but doesn't fill the groups of the first one properly:

[image]

[image]

More specifically, it doesn't capture the first group which is the variable name and this is the one I care about? Am I missing something?

EDIT:

I need it to match/not match all of the following strings:

```
@ala-bala__portokala: fade(@color_k1, 40%); // MATCH
@ala-bala: rgb(255, 255, 255); // MATCH
@ala-bala: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.2); // MATCH
@ala-bala__portokala: #cccccc; // MATCH
@ala-bala__portokala: 1px solid @color_w; // MATCH
@ala-bala__portokala: @color_r1; // MATCH
@ala-b: @colozr_p; // NOT MATCH
@ala-b: 2px; // NOT MATCH
```

EDIT 2:

So, after some alterations, this is the final regex which matches everything properly:

```
(@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+): .*(?:(@color_[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)|(#[0-9a-fA-F]{3,})|(rgb[a]?[(].*[)])).*;
```

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/ZFibAP/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/umXJgF/1

Comment: If you only care about the first group wouldn't something simpler like this be easier (@\w+): (?:#[A-F0-9]{3,}|@color_\w+);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st from your source strings does not contain `#...` part,
so the 1st variant will not be matched.

So the regex processor tries the 2nd variant (after "|"),
which contains **only one** capturing group, matching *@color_white*.

Probably your intention was:

- First find a match with `@colorVariable...:`.
- Then find a match with either `@<color_name>` or `#<numbers>`.

Change your regex to:

```
(@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+): (?:(#[0-9a-fA-F]{3,})|(@color_[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+));
```

Note that now it contains:

- First capturing group matching `@colorVariable...`.
- Colon and space
- A non-capturing group, with 2 variants (capturing groups 2 and 3)
  for both color specifications **inside this group**.
- The terminating `;`.

Comment: Uhm, yes, it turns out the '|' screws it up because I forgot to enclose the whole expression after the ':' in brackets as to use the OR operator in the proper way. Thanks!